# How do I install XAMPP to another directory on Windows 10?

Tags: xampp, windows-10

I'm having the hardest time installing `XAMPP` on C:\Development\xampp on `Windows 10`. I would like my C drive to be as clean as possible so I'm moving as many dev tools to the `Development folder` as I can to achieve this. I get an error towards the end of the XAMPP installation about a problem running the post-install step. It then suggests I install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable, which I already have the 2012 version installed. Originally XAMPP was installed on C:\ with no problems.

How do I install XAMPP to the above directory or any directory other than C:\?

**Edit:**

I have tried installing XAMPP portable and now receive the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no longer on Windows so I can't re-test, but as I recall, the easiest way I managed this was to use the portable version of xampp.
Make sure to run the shell setup script so that it recognizes it's location properly.

You can get it from [Apache Friends](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.15/)
Or from [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp)

Comment: This seems like a viable solution although I can't seem to find a windows portable version of XAMPP. Is it distributed by [Apache Friends](https://www.apachefriends.org)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm now getting a new error with no changes to previous errors.

Comment: This is odd because you aren't supposed to run an installer for Portable Xampp, just `setup.cmd`
Also, make sure you've cleared all temporary and previous xampp files (`users/temp, C:\\`)